# Insert columns by column index

Tags: r

Given the following data frame:

```
> header = c("A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3")
> df = matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow = 1)
> colnames(df) = header
> df
     A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I know the column index numbers of the headers containing "2" by:

```
> index2 = grep("2", colnames(df))
> index2
[1] 2 5
```

I want to add two extra columns named "A2.1","A2.2" and "B2.1", "B2.2" next to the columns with index 2 and 5, so that:

```
     A1 A2 A2.1 A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B2.1 B2.2 B3
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0    0
```

Ho can I do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to insert columns based on 'index2', one option is

```
df1 <- cbind(df, do.call(cbind,
          replicate(2,df[,index2, drop=FALSE], simplify=FALSE)))
df2 <- df1[,order(colnames(df1)), drop=FALSE]
colnames(df2) <- make.unique(colnames(df2))
df2
#     A1 A2 A2.1 A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B2.1 B2.2 B3
#[1,]  0  0    0    0  0  0  0    0    0  0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an effective and elegant way to solve the issue. Cheers to you!

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100),ncol=5))
colnames(df) <- LETTERS[1:ncol(df)]
B.1 <- runif(20)
df <- cbind(df,B.1)
df <- df[,order(colnames(df))]
#> head(df)
#          A          B        B.1         C          D         E
#1 0.1137034 0.31661245 0.03545673 0.5533336 0.86483383 0.9264005
#2 0.6222994 0.30269337 0.56507611 0.6464061 0.04185728 0.4719097
#3 0.6092747 0.15904600 0.28025778 0.3118243 0.31718216 0.1426153
#4 0.6233794 0.03999592 0.20419632 0.6218192 0.01374994 0.5442698
#5 0.8609154 0.21879954 0.13373890 0.3297702 0.23902573 0.1961747
#6 0.6403106 0.81059855 0.32568192 0.5019975 0.70649462 0.8985805
```

It means that you are first attaching the column on the right with `cbind()` and order the columns sequence afterwards. Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't answering the question IIRC (@David correct me if I'm wrong). OP wants to create these columns *programmatically* by a *certain condition* while you just manually created some random column (without any condition) and `cbind` it.

Comment: The random numbers are merely used as an example to show how a realistic column could be inserted into a dataframe. My understanding was that the goal is to insert a new column and to obtain a dataframe with columns which are alphanumerically ordered. The number 2 could easily be replaced with the ".1" in my example without loss of generality. My interpretation of the use of `index2` in the OP was to show the attempts that were made so far. I suggested another way to place the new column at the correct position.

Comment: The OP is programmatically creating and index of column to be added. See @akruns answer for an example on how this index should be used.