# Insert columns by column index (unaltered column order)

Tags: r

Given the following data frame:

```
> header = c("A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","AB1", "AB2", "AB3")
> df = matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),nrow = 1)
> colnames(df) = header
> df
     A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 AB1 AB2 AB3
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
```

I know the column index numbers of the headers containing "2" by:

```
> index2 = grep("2", colnames(df))
> index2
[1] 2 5 8
```

I want to add two extra columns named "A2.1","A2.2","B2.1", "B2.2", etc. (or an alternative nomenclature that allows me to distinguish them) next to the columns with index 2,5 and 8, so that:

```
     A1 A2 A2.1 A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B2.1 B2.2 B3 AB1 AB2 AB2.1 AB2.2 AB3
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0    0    0   0     0     0   0
```

I solved a similar issue in the following post: [Insert columns by column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560311/insert-columns-by-column-index/31560504#31560504)

However, in the resulting data frame the columns are alphabetically ordered, and I do not want that.

Does anybody know how to fix the ordering issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the difference between this question  and the one you already posted here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560311/insert-columns-by-column-index/31560504#31560504 The output and ordering of the columns provided by the answer is the same.

Comment: @mpalanco if you will run akruns solution on the data in this question, you will get  different result. Either way, I think that just subsetting is better than replicating the whole column several times.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Now I see, thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would approach this differently. Instead of replicating the columns, I will just subset the columns I need several times (3 times in this case). This way the order of the columns will be stored.

Creating the subsetting index

```
indx <- unlist(lapply(1:ncol(df), function(x) if(x %in% index2) rep(x, 3) else x))
## [1] 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 8 8 9
```

Subsetting the columns and renaming

```
df1 <- df[, indx, drop = FALSE]
colnames(df1) <- make.unique(colnames(df1))
df1
#      A1 A2 A2.1 A2.2 A3 B1 B2 B2.1 B2.2 B3 AB1 AB2 AB2.1 AB2.2 AB3
# [1,]  0  0    0    0  0  0  0    0    0  0   0   0     0     0   0
```